# Height of block element which contains an inline-block element

Tags: html, block, css

I am confused when calculating the height of a block element which contains an inline-block element, and the code is below:

```
<div style="background: orange;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
<div style="background: green;">
    <div style="background: #d9d9d9; display: inline-block; font-size: 48px; line-height: 12px;">H</div>
</div>
```

and you can find example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uAFLk/).


My question is why the height of the parent element is 20px under chrome? I think it should be 0 due to its child has no height.

And in the second example, how to calculate the parent height when the child line-height is less than font-size?

Comment: Not answering your question (the "why" part), but to make the orange box 0px, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uAFLk/1/

Comment: yes, it's done well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks containing `inline-block` elements (even empty ones) receive height equal to the its calculated line-height. Set `font-size` to `0` and `line-height` to `1`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/a28Fr/1/)

Comment: Works with `font-size` too.

Comment: Edited the answer. `Font-size` should be set to `0` as well, right.

Comment: the default font-size is 16px in chrome, and the default line-height is normal, so the parent div's height = 16 * normal?

Comment: And I added line-height in the child of the first example, but the height of parent is still 20px.

Comment: @exizt sorry for forgetting @ you

Comment: @odin `line-height` should be set for the PARENT element. The height of line (and, therefore, height of the block containing the line) is equal to its `font-size` or `line-height` (whichever is larger).